# Meteor yogiben:admin refuses to update collection

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I use yogiben:admin package for one of my meteor apps. The problems is that when I try to edit a collection through the admin page it goes to a blank page with a text:

> Couldn't find a template named "(*)" or "(*)". Are you sure you
>   defined it?

I tried to attach a template to the admin config file in the following way:

```
Photos: {templates: {
        new: {
          name: 'postWYSIGEditor'
        },
        edit: {
          name: 'postWYSIGEditor',
          data: {
             post: Meteor.isClient && Session.get('admin_doc')
          }
        }
      }},
```